# How do I find the size class of my window in a class method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a couple class methods defined in one of my classes. I would like to be able for the class methods to return different values based on the size class of the screen / window.

I don't have access to `UITraitCollection` because I don't have an instance of the class. How would I go about getting this information otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it using `[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.traitCollection`

Comment: Thanks! And instead of `appDelegate`, it's just `delegate`.

Comment: Good catch! I have a class method on my delegate class so I can access it as `[SampleAppDelegate appDelegate]` and I originally started typing that.